# My feature detection code which uses openCV4Android , doesn't work?

Tags: opencv

I wrote this code to detect features in real time using opencv4android.But somehow this code doesn't work and i cannot find the error in this code but i guess erroneous code is this {detector.detect(mRgba, keypoints)}.I'm sorry for my poor explanation. i'm really new to this subject. please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2{
        private CameraBridgeViewBase    mOpenCvCameraView;
        private static final String     TAG = "feature detection";
        private Mat             mRgba, mGray;
        private FeatureDetector         detector;
        private DescriptorExtractor     SurfExtractor;
        private MatOfKeyPoint       keypoints;

            BaseLoaderCallback blc = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                if(status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS){
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(0);
            }else{
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            };
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.cam);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this,blc);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
                mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
            mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8SC4);
            detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
            SurfExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {
            mRgba.release();
        }

        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
                detector.detect(mRgba, keypoints);
            Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, keypoints, mRgba);
            return mRgba;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It gives null pointer eception.

Comment: what does the above actually detect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the opencv java wrappers, you can pass an empty Mat for result/output values, but not a null one.

so you have to call at least m = new Mat(), or in this case, keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint():

```
    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
            detector.detect(mRgba, keypoints);
        Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, keypoints, mRgba);
        return mRgba;
    }
```

(same story with the descriptors in your next step, btw.)

Comment: thanks , but now it gives an exception which is "incorrect type of input image"

Answer (score 0):

It has to change inputFrame.rgba(); to inputFrame.gray(); as well